# Boost.Program_options not linking correctly under Clang

Tags: c++, boost, g++, clang++, boost-program-options

The following initial example from the [**Boost.Program_options**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#idp343085776) documentation

```
// Copyright Vladimir Prus 2002-2004.
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
// (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt
// or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

/* The simplest usage of the library.
 */

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try {

        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help", "produce help message")
            ("compression", po::value<double>(), "set compression level")
        ;

        po::variables_map vm;        
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);    

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            cout << desc << "\n";
            return 0;
        }

        if (vm.count("compression")) {
            cout << "Compression level was set to " 
                 << vm["compression"].as<double>() << ".\n";
        } else {
            cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
        }
    }
    catch(exception& e) {
        cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    catch(...) {
        cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compiles, links and runs correctly under g++ ([**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c884fa073e00a43e)), but not under clang ([**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d67ccf3be7c4a834)) with error

> /tmp/main-47ef95.o: In function
>   `boost::program_options::typed_value<double, char>::name() const':
>   main.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcE4nameEv]+0x49):
>   undefined reference to`boost::program_options::arg'
>   /tmp/main-47ef95.o: In function
>   `boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)':
>   main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_i]+0x39):
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

**Question**: what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GCC C++ ABI changed in version 5](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/) which can cause some object incompatibilities:

> Users just need to make sure that they are building with the ABI used
>   by the libraries that they depend on.

I think it is likely that your version of boost has been built using GCC 5 (CoLiRu has 5.2 installed), and the resulting libraries are not compatible with clang++ objects.

[This blog post](http://allanmcrae.com/2015/06/the-case-of-gcc-5-1-and-the-two-c-abis/) discusses GCC5 and Clang compatibility, and links to an [open LLVM bug  to restore ABI interop with GCC](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23529).